# Django Get content from FK of FK

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm facing troubles with my django project.
I have a three layer model:

**model.py**

```
class PLC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Measure(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('PLC', 'address', 'is_bit')
    PLC = models.ForeignKey(PLC, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.IntegerField()
    is_bit = models.BooleanField()

class MeasureValue(models.Model):
    measure = models.ForeignKey(Measure, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.TextField()
```

In my **view.py**, I want to be able to get measures values out of the plc

```
class PLCViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PLC.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PLCSerializer


def measures(request, id):
    plc = PLC.objects.get(id=id)
    measures = Measure.objects.filter(PLC=id)
    values = MeasureValue.objects.filter(measure__PLC=id)

    context = {
        'PLC': plc,
        'MEASURES': measures,
        'VALUES': values
    }

    return render(request, 'measures.html', context)
```

Unfortunately, i cannot make a correct `filter()` (data are stored in sqlite base).

Comment: What are you seeing that is not what you expect? What you have looks right to me, though you could/should be using `PLC=plc` rather than `PLC=id`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, `PLC=plc` is better :)

Comment: What I want to acheive is get the values (from `MeasureValues`) related to the object `Measure` which is itself related to `PLC`.
But i cannot retreived the data with the correct filter.

Comment: When a do a `for i in values: print(i)`, i got 
`MeasureValue object (1)  MeasureValue object (2)  MeasureValue object (3)`

Comment: That's because `values` is a collection of `MeasureValue` instances. If you want the `MeasureValue.value` text field, you need to access it via the `value` property:  `values[0].value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into `prefetch_related` and [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)? Those would allow you to pull the related fields when fetching the `PLC` instance. Then you can access them as follows:

```
plc = PLC.objects.prefetch_related('measure_set__measurevalue_set').filter(id=id).first()
plc.measure_set.all() # QuerySet of `Measure` that are filtered to the `plc`
for measure in plc.measure_set.all():
    measure.measurevalue_set.all() # QuerySet of `MeasureValue` that are filtered to the `measure` therefore `plc`
```

Comment: So the `prefech_related` is doing the filter for my FKs but I don't get how to use the for statement in my `context` and then integrate it in my html file.

Comment: That was just an example of how to iterate over the related fields. Please check out the docs on [relationship fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). In regards of how to render things in a template, I would suggest reviewing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/. The sections on [A shortcut: get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404) and [Use the Template System](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system) specifically.

Comment: I know how to make the html, I just dont get how to get the `measurevalue_set` from the `measure_set` I mean, I obviously cannot do `values= plc.measure_set.measurevalue_set.all()`.
Might need one more little tip :)

Comment: Try nesting your `for x in y` loops in the template.

Comment: Like that :
`{% for MEASURE in plc.measure_set.all %}`
                                    `<tr>`
                                       `<td>{{ measure.measurevalue_set.value }}</td>`
                                       `<td>{{ measure.measurevalue_set.value_type }}</td>`
                                        `<td>{{ measure.measurevalue_set.update_time }}</td>`
                                    `</tr>`
                                `{% endfor %}`

Comment: Because I don't get any result with that :/

Comment: You need `{% for measure in plc.measure_set.all %}` to match your other template tags. Then you need to iterate over the collection of `measure.measurevalue_set`. Because `measure.measurevalue_set` reverse FK objects manager to a collection of MeasureValue instances. So you'd end up with `{% for measure_value in measure.measurevalue_set.all %} {{ measure_value.value }} {% endfor %}`